How to inscribe a triangle with side-length 1 into a hyperbola, analogous to inscribing a triangle with hypotenuse 1 into a circle?
I have recently been looking at the Hyperbolic Trigonometric functions, and I've run into this unique dilemma which I haven't seen a satisfying answer to. I would ask that you watch this video before answering:
Firstly, let's set my question up.
I know that a triangle with a fixed hypotenuse length of 1 can be inscribed inside a circle, like so. I also know that the hyperbola and it's associated trig functions can be thought to come from a triangle which, instead of having a fixed hypotenuse length of 1, has instead a fixed side length of 1 like this.
My question is, how do you inscribe a triangle with side-length 1, into a hyperbola, such that it is analogous to the triangle with unit hypotenuse in the usual case? Most commonly, I have seen diagrams like this, however, this does not show a triangle with side-length of 1. I have heard it may be something to do with hyperbolic rotation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

We can identify a unit segment in the hyperbolic case by invoking the Gudermannian function. The following uses a different construction from that in Wikipedia, but renders the function directly in terms of an angle.

Start with the origin $O=(0,0)$ and a point $P=(\cosh u,\sinh u)$ on the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$. Drop a perpendicular from $P$ to the $x$-axis, whose foot is $Q$. Then construct two circles: one with diameter $OQ$, the other centered at $Q$ and passing through $P$. The circles intersect at a point $R$ on the same side of the $x$-axis as $P$, such that $|QR|=\sinh u,|OQ|=\cosh u$, and $\angle ORQ$ is a right angle. Then from the Pythagorean Theorem and SOH CAH TOA, $OR$ is a unit segment whose angle from the $x$-axis is the aforementioned Gudermannian function:
$$\theta=\arctan(\sinh u)\equiv \text{gd}(u)$$
If $P$ is allowed to traverse the entire hyperbola, then $R$ as determined by this construction will traverse the whole unit circle, and we may regard $P$ on the hyperbola as a projection of $R$ on the circle. This firms the basis for the Mercator projection commonly used in global mapping and navigation.

+1. I hope you don't mind that I added a diagram of the construction. (Of course, you can always feel free to roll-back my edit.)

Yeah thanks for the diagram.
